# Linq Lambda GroupJoin and ToList()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm using in entity framework some GroupJoin in order to aggregate lists of 'b' elements for an 'a' master. My problem is that once i return the query.ToList() object that comes from db, I cannot extract the IEnumerable elements because I'm outside of their context. I thouhgt to put a `.ToList()` "bList.Tolist()" but I think that a tolist there will cause the immediate execution of the whole query, with bad performances. Can you help me?

```
class Result
{
  IEnumerable<string> Strings { get; set; }
}
```

```
using (var context = new TicketingContext())
            {
                var query = context.A.GroupJoin(context.B,
                    a => a.IDA,
                    b => b.IDA,
                    (a, bList) => new { a, Result = new Result { Strings = bList } }
                    )
                var res = query.ToList();
            }
```

my question is, if i add a tolist() like in the following code the whole query will be executed? is there a turnaround?

```
using (var context = new TicketingContext())
            {
                var query = context.A.GroupJoin(context.B,
                    a => a.IDA,
                    b => b.IDA,
                    (a, bList) => new { a, Result = new Result { Strings = bList.**ToList()** } }
                    )
                var res = query.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I cannot navigate the IEnumerable elements because they are not concrete"? What are you trying to do? Also, your example uses `Join` not `GroupJoin`.

Comment: Hi J. thanks for the response. The problem is that outside the using context i cannot do obj.Result.Strings.ToList() because it is an IEnumerable. Only inside using i can do it. To avoid this problem my solution is to do  ... a,  Result = new Result {Strings = bList.ToList()} but i'm not sure it is a good solution in terms of performances.

Comment: Ah ok. The reason that you can't do the `ToList` outside of the context isn't because it is an `IEnumerable` per se. `IEnumerable` is an interface that simply defines an iterator, that could be implemented in a number of ways. When using Entity Framework, that implementation is to execute an SQL query on a database, but once outside your using block, the database connection is disposed.

Comment: How do you expect to work with the results of the query without the immediate execution of the query? LINQ to a database must always return the entire query to work with the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

Because outside the `using()`, the `dbContext` is disposed. So you need to `.ToList()` as you wish.

```
 using (var context = new TicketingContext())
 {
     var res = context.A.GroupJoin(context.B,
                a => a.IDA,
                b => b.IDA,
                (a, bList) => new { a, Result = new Result { Strings = bList.ToList() } }
                ).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Phong for your help. I know that outside the context the object is disposed but i'm worried about the "ToList()" you added. I think the code you wrote will execute 2 queries rather than one.

Comment: In my opinion, EF has optimized by combining all queries to run at a time. So you no need to worry about that.

Comment: @MattiaP. That really depends on which version of EF you are using: EF Core 2.x, EF Core 2.2, EF Core 3.x, EF 6.x.

Comment: @NetMage thanks for your response, i'm using EF Core, the point is that i cant find documentation about what happens when you perform a ToList() inside a GroupJoin, i have no idea of what part of the query will be executed. I know in a normal EF iqueryable the ToList() will immediate execute the whole query, i'm trying to understand if a complex query, with n joins and m groupjoins EF will be good at performance or i'm using ef in a not proper way.

Comment: @MattiaP. The version of EF Core matters a lot. A `GroupJoin` is no different than any other construct, putting a `ToList` will immediately fully evaluate the query.